# No matching version found for @vue/cli-plugin-router@3.12.1 after npm audit fix --force

Tags: python, django, vue.js, npm

I have just run this: npm audit fix --force

But after that I got this issue:

```
djackets_vue@0.1.0 serve
vue-cli-service serve

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '@vue/cli-plugin-router'
Require stack:
- C:\DjangoWeb\venv\Scripts\djackets_django - Copy\djackets_vue\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\Service.js
- C:\DjangoWeb\venv\Scripts\djackets_django - Copy\djackets_vue\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\bin\vue-cli-service.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at idToPlugin (C:\DjangoWeb\venv\Scripts\djackets_django - Copy\djackets_vue\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\Service.js:150:14)
    at C:\DjangoWeb\venv\Scripts\djackets_django - Copy\djackets_vue\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\Service.js:190:20
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Service.resolvePlugins (C:\DjangoWeb\venv\Scripts\djackets_django - Copy\djackets_vue\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\Service.js:176:10)
    at new Service (C:\DjangoWeb\venv\Scripts\djackets_django - Copy\djackets_vue\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\Service.js:34:25)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\DjangoWeb\venv\Scripts\djackets_django - Copy\djackets_vue\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\bin\vue-cli-service.js:16:17) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\DjangoWeb\\venv\\Scripts\\djackets_django - Copy\\djackets_vue\\node_modules\\@vue\\cli-service\\lib\\Service.js',
    'C:\\DjangoWeb\\venv\\Scripts\\djackets_django - Copy\\djackets_vue\\node_modules\\@vue\\cli-service\\bin\\vue-cli-service.js'
  ]
}
```

---

### Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "djackets_vue",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "bulma": "^0.9.3",
    "bulma-toast": "^2.4.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.0-0",
    "vuex": "^4.0.0-0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.3.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "3.12.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.12.1",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.26.5",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2"
  }
}
```

I have just tried to unistall node_modules and npm then reinstall all of this, but still nothing.

Any idea?
Thank you in advance